# Synchronising subset of mongodb on local machine

Tags: mongodb, nedb

I would like to synchronise a subset of a `Mongodb` onto my local machine which would have a lightweight database like `NeDB`. What are the methods available to see what is the difference between the data in the two database, so that I could retrieve only the data that have changed?